# GCOVR - File not found

Tags: windows, gcov, gcovr

Windows 11
GCOV v6.0
Python 3.11.3
gcc.exe (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 12.1.0
gcov (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 12.1.0

I compile my project, run the executable and get a full set of .gcda and .gcno files as expected, however when I run:

gcovr -r . within the folder with all of the .gcda and .gcno files I get:

PS C:\emwi_testframework\Application\Project\GCC\obj> gcovr -r .
(ERROR) Trouble processing 'C:/emwi_testframework/Application/Project/GCC/obj/ewheap.gcda' with working directory 'C:\emwi_testframework\Application\Project\GCC\obj'.
Stdout of gcov was >>None<< End of stdout
Stderr of gcov was >>None<< End of stderr
Current processed gcov file was None.
Use option --verbose to get extended informations.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gcovr\workers.py", line 80, in worker
work(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gcovr\gcov.py", line 323, in process_datafile
done = run_gcov_and_process_files(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gcovr\gcov.py", line 530, in run_gcov_and_process_files
gcov_cmd.identify_and_cache_capabilities()
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gcovr\gcov.py", line 417, in identify_and_cache_capabilities
if self.__check_gcov_option("--demangled-names"):
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gcovr\gcov.py", line 451, in __check_gcov_option
if option in self.__get_help_output():
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gcovr\gcov.py", line 435, in __get_help_output
gcov_process = self.__get_gcov_process(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gcovr\gcov.py", line 470, in __get_gcov_process
return subprocess.Popen(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1024, in **init**
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1509, in _execute_child
hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gcovr\workers.py", line 80, in worker
work(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gcovr\gcov.py", line 323, in process_datafile
done = run_gcov_and_process_files(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gcovr\gcov.py", line 530, in run_gcov_and_process_files
gcov_cmd.identify_and_cache_capabilities()
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gcovr\gcov.py", line 417, in identify_and_cache_capabilities
if self.__check_gcov_option("--demangled-names"):
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gcovr\gcov.py", line 451, in __check_gcov_option
if option in self.__get_help_output():
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gcovr\gcov.py", line 435, in __get_help_output
gcov_process = self.__get_gcov_process(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gcovr\gcov.py", line 470, in __get_gcov_process
return subprocess.Popen(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1024, in **init**
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1509, in *execute_child
hp, ht, pid, tid = *winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
(ERROR) Uncaught EXCEPTION
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 198, in *run_module_as_main
File "", line 88, in *run_code
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\gcovr.exe_*main**.py", line 7, in 
sys.exit(main())
^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gcovr_*main**.py", line 328, in main
covdata = collect_coverage_from_gcov(options)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gcovr_*main**.py", line 380, in collect_coverage_from_gcov
with Workers(
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gcovr\workers.py", line 173, in **exit**
self.wait()
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gcovr\workers.py", line 164, in wait
raise self.exceptions[0][1]
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gcovr_*main**.py", line 387, in collect_coverage_from_gcov
contexts = pool.wait()
^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gcovr\workers.py", line 164, in wait
raise self.exceptions[0][1]
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gcovr\workers.py", line 80, in worker
work(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gcovr\gcov.py", line 323, in process_datafile
done = run_gcov_and_process_files(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gcovr\gcov.py", line 530, in run_gcov_and_process_files
gcov_cmd.identify_and_cache_capabilities()
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gcovr\gcov.py", line 417, in identify_and_cache_capabilities
if self.__check_gcov_option("--demangled-names"):
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gcovr\gcov.py", line 451, in __check_gcov_option
if option in self.__get_help_output():
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gcovr\gcov.py", line 435, in __get_help_output
gcov_process = self.__get_gcov_process(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gcovr\gcov.py", line 470, in __get_gcov_process
return subprocess.Popen(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1024, in **init**
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1509, in _execute_child
hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

I would appreciate any suggestions as I am new to gcov.

Comment: How do you invoke GCC? Is it in your PATH? What happens when you run `gcov --help`? Gcovr needs gcov from the GCC project, which should have been compiled alongside the compiler. If gcov is somewhere else, you can tell gcovr about this with `gcovr --gcov-executable C:/path/to/gcov`. See also: https://gcovr.com/en/stable/guide/compiling.html#choosing-the-right-gcov-executable